# Leveraging emotional intelligence effectively in choice process

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-development, emotional-intelligence

I am stuck between choosing between a few options. I have analyzed them rationally and yet I cannot decide what is the most suited for me.

I have read that a powerful tool here would be leveraging emotional intelligence and "feel" more the various options. Yet, I have never invested on this skill and I do not know any practical way to let EI help me at this stage.

The other factor is that the opportunity is short lived (few days).

> What practical ways do you know to apply EI to my thought process, that is effective in a short amount of time?

Any reference/material is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you can start with:

> Salovey, P., & Mayer, J. D. (1990). Emotional Intelligence. Imagination, Cognition and Personality, 9(3), 185–211. https://doi.org/10.2190/DUGG-P24E-52WK-6CDG

public document in PDF is also [available](https://center.uoregon.edu/StartingStrong/uploads/STARTINGSTRONG2016/HANDOUTS/KEY_46201/pub153_SaloveyMayerICP1990_OCR.pdf).

once you grasped EI framework, you could proceed with using it in your actual needs.

whether you have enough time to project 20+ long document on your own topics is subject of your circumstances.